# How to measure a spike in data

Tags: dataset

For example, if I had data like the number of daily coronavirus cases for different countries and I wanted to compare the 'intensity' of the spikes (abnormally large number of cases), what statistical method should I use? Thank you!

Comment: If you define what is expected somehow, then you can define what is the departure from expected. This principle appears everywhere in statistics from looking at deviations from a mean through chi-square tests using counted frequencies to regression-like residuals, and beyond. With coronavirus I would think a minimum processing would be subtract out day of the week effects first by taking a moving average (or just possibly median or geometric mean). That could just be a start.

Comment: No one voted to close so far, but the brevity here didn't encourage any detailed answers until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A spike in data is usually measured as a [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score). And as a kind of rule of thumb, z-scores lower than -3 or higher than +3 could be considered extreme, as 99.7% of values in a normal distribution should fall between -3 and +3.

This requires you to make the assumption that your data distribution is normal.

Because it is a number, the z-score satisfies your desire to be able to compare different spikes in the data. Of course, you could have just compared their absolute values. But with a time-series you could have a moving mean and standard deviation. So if you want to use this to discover unusual daily peaks you might using a moving window of the past 60 days, and base z-scores off the mean and s.d. in its 60 day window.

Aside: Having found the spikes, you will then want to sanity-check them. For instance, with "raw" reported deaths you will find the biggest spikes are just after weekends and public holidays. So you may choose to first smooth that raw data with a 7-day moving average, and then run your 60-day window on the smoothed data; remember though that all peaks and troughs will have been smoothed by this, not just the ones that occur every 7 days.

Comment: This starts with dubious advice and then improves on it.   I wouldn't go further than saying that spikes are usually measured as differences, and sometimes as ratios (differences on a log scale). The OP asks about counts that must be zero or positive and even if we are focusing as we are on departures from expected, it is far from obvious that normal distribution is a reference.

Comment: @NickCox Yes, when values have to be >=0 I'd be raising a flag if subtracting 3 or 4 s.d. from the mean took it below zero. And you might want to try detrending the data (in the example of coronavirus cases they seem to either be rising or falling, rather than mean-reverting). But as you noted it is a relatively brief question, on a topic it is possible to go very deep on.